# How long does it take to travel by road from Buenos Aires to Rio De Janeiro?

Tags: driving, buses, brazil, argentina

if any of you people know how long does it take to travel by road (bus/car) from Buenos Aires to Rio De Janeiro, please tell me. I love travelling on land, and am planning to visit South America Next Month.

Answer (score 1):

It takes about 40 hours by bus.

that's according to the schedule of [omnilneas](http://www.omnilineas.com/argentina/bus/retiro/rio-de-janeiro-brasil/)

I would recommend to break the journey into several pieces, there are lots of things to see on the way.